# Folder Structure For A React Apollo-GraphQl Heroku App

Tags: reactjs, heroku, graphql, directory-structure

I've been learning GraphQL for a while and also learned how to connect it with react front-end but I'm a bit confuse about the folder that I should follow for an app with client & server. Also I'll be deploying it to Heroku if that's relevant to the folder structure.